# My ajax call just stopped working

Tags: ajax

I have been using ajax call to fetch data from my remote server on my cordova app/localhost, It just stopped working for no reason, but the same ajax call is still working locally, Im using wampserver to host my site locally,
Below is the code that fails to fetch data but it has been working just fine

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://wingup.byethost4.com/trial.php',
            type: 'GET',         
            data: {phone_number:"phone_number"},
            success:function(data){
                console.log("message was sent");
            },error:function(err){
                console.log("message was not sent");
            }
        });
```

But if i change the url to my localhost it works, Please help me with annoying error

Comment: In what specific way does it "stop working"?  Is there an error on the browser console?  Is the HTTP request made?  What is the server's response?  When you debug this, where/how specifically does this fail?

Comment: It does not fetch the data anymore, if debug it in firefox, it says 200 ok and it also say connection used to fetch this resource was not secure

Answer (score 1):

It may have the error like this

> CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

It does not allow remote access. Check this related setting on your server.

Comment: I have added ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my server but still no change